# modify the 'agsm' bibliography style in two ways

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

I am using LaTeX with the `article` document class. The Bibtex bibliography style that I am using is `agsm`, part of the Harvard family of bibliography styles.

I have two questions:

(1) If I cite an entry of type `@book`, then in the reference list I get *publisher, address*. I would like to re-arrange this order to *address: publisher*. Which part of `agsm.bst` should I modify?

(2) I would like to change single quotation marks ' ' to double quotation marks " " for setting off the title of entries of type `@article`. Which part of `agsm.bst` should I focus on?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `apsr` bibliography style you wish to modify? To the best of my knowledge, for entries of type `@book`,  the `apsr` bibliography style is programmed to typeset the address and publisher as "address: publisher", not as "publisher, address".  For entries of type `@article`, the `apsr` bib style uses double quotes, not single quotes, to encase the contents of the `title` field. (For entries of type `@book`, the title field is rendered in italics.) These default settings are quite different from what you say the `apsr` bibliography style does by default. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico: you are correct. I made a typo. I am using "agsm", not "apsr" as early version I raised the question. I did correct the question.

Comment: Please also correct the other two instances of `apsr` in your posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Locate the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `agsm-mod.bst`. (Do not edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `agsm-mod.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use to edit your  .tex files will do fine.
- Let's tackle the easier task first: Changing the quoting style from single quotes to double quotes. In `agsm-mod.bst`, locate the function called `quote`. (In my copy of this file, the `quote` function starts on line 155.) In this function, locate the following line:

  ```
      { "`" swap$ * "'" * }
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
      { "``" swap$ * "''" * }
  ```

  This change will affect not only how titles of entries of type `@article` are typeset; it will also affect the titles of entries of type `@misc` and `@booklet`. I'm assuming that you're OK with this.
- The much harder task, actually, is changing *publisher, address* to *address: publisher* for entries of type `@book`. It turns out to be necessary to provide several new BibTeX functions in order to accomplish this task. This is because the stock `agsm` style is programmed to use commas between fields *everywhere*; using a colon between two particular fields (here: `address` and `publisher`) is not something this bib style does easily.

  Start off by inserting the following code chunk between the functions `multi.page.check` and `format.pages`.

  ```
  FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
  { swap$
    duplicate$ missing$
      {
        swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
        ""
      }
      { duplicate$ empty$
          {
            swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
          }
          { swap$
            pop$
          }
        if$
      }
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
  { swap$
    duplicate$ missing$
      {
        pop$ pop$
        ""
      }
      { duplicate$ empty$
          {
            swap$ pop$
          }
          { swap$
            pop$
          }
        if$
      }
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
  { 't :=
    ""
    address empty$ t empty$ and
      'skip$
      {
        address "address" bibinfo.check *
        t empty$
          'skip$
          { address empty$
              'skip$
              { ": " * }
            if$
            t *
          }
        if$
      }
    if$
  }

  FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
  { publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
  }
  ```
- Next, locate the `book` function in the file `agsm-mod.bst`. In this function, locate the following two lines

  ```
        publisher "publisher" output.check
        address output
  ```

  Replace these two lines with (I think you can already guess...)

  ```
        format.publisher.address output
  ```

  And, while you're at it, you should replace the same pair of lines in the functions `inbook` and `incollection` as well. (Just search for the two remaining instances of `publisher "publisher" output.check` in the bst file.)
- Save the bst file either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- Finally, in your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{agsm}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{agsm-mod}
  ```

  and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

---

For good measure, here's an MWE (minimum working example) that demonstrates the result of using the `agsm-mod` bibliography style.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{a,
  author   = "Anne Author",
  title    = "Thoughts",
  year     = 3001,
  journal  = "Circularity Today",
  volume   = 1,
  number   = 2,
  pages    = "3-4",
}
@book{b,
  author   = "Brenda Buthor",
  title    = "Further Thoughts",
  year     = 4001,
  publisher= "Publisher",
  address  = "Some Place, XY",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}
\bibliographystyle{agsm-mod}%

\begin{document}
\cite{a}, \cite{b}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is really perfect code. It works well for my case. Thank you very much for your great support.

Comment: for further customization of  my bibliography style, can you suggest me to which documents I should address to understand "code chunk" in the *.bst files?

Comment: @VũVõ - I'm not sure I understand your question. In computer coding, a "chunk" is (at least as I understand it) a term for a block of code. That's the sense of the term I meant to use. To be more specific, the chunk I was referring to consists of four [4] BibTeX functions: `bibinfo.warn`, `bibinfo.check`, `format.org.or.pub`, and `format.publisher.address`.

Comment: I mean the code that is presented in the *.bst :-). I understood some parts of the code, but not throughout the code. This makes you laughing me coz  it so ambitious  :-), But I really want to understand it as much as I can.

Comment: @VũVõ - The BibTeX infix-style (aka "reverse Polish notation"-type) programming language isn't easy to master. For an introduction to this programming language and to BibTeX in general, see the 48-page document entitled [Tame the BeaST](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf).

Comment: I have another question about re-arrange authors' last names and their first names in the agsm.bst style. I am going to raise the question in another threat. If you can help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @VũVõ - threat or thread? :-)

Comment: :-) it should be "thread", not threat. kaka :-)