# Modify NatBib Bibliography List Style/Layout (CiteThemRight)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, layout

I am currently working on my Bachelors thesis with TexLive 2018 in TexStudio.
My University demands the usage of the CiteThemRight reference styling, which is an adaption of the Harvard referencing standard. (This question is edited based on the discussion in the comments)

Here's how it looks right now:
[image: Current Literature Layout]

Here's the current status with highlights and notes on what needs to change. Please note that the date added text should of course be in the same font and size as the rest, I just edited the picture badly.

[image: Wanted Literature Layout]

This is how the literature is currently defined:

```
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

I have found some questions, linked in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483994/modify-natbib-bibliography-list-style-layout-citethemright/484005?noredirect=1#comment1223760_484005) comment where @Mico's answers suggest changing the style defined in the agsm.bst (more, a copy thereof). I have tried to find my way in the file but cant make heads or tails with it. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The strength of the `natbib` citation management package is its control over the appearance of citation call-outs. The `natbib` package doesn't have much of a role in the way the bib entries are formatted. Which bibliography style do you use at present?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Currently, I define the bib style with `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Note the use of the `@misc` entry type and the placement of both the URL and date-accessed information in a field called `note`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{bach:99,
  author  = "Bach, J.",
  year    = 1999, 
  title   = "{Test} Strategy: {What} is it? {What} does it look like?",
  note     = "URL: \url{http://www.satisfice.com/presentations/strategy.pdf} (\emph{Date Accessed: 1~March 2019})",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm} % part of the 'harvard' package
\usepackage{xurl}
\makeatletter
\def\url@itstyle{\def\UrlFont{\itshape}} % define a new URL style called "it"
\makeatother
\urlstyle{it}

\begin{document}
\citet{bach:99}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, this looks very promising. This means I would have to manually edit the .bib file? I will try this as soon as I am able!

Comment: @JFNT - You seemed to indicate earlier that you must use the `agsm` bibliography style. When using the `agsm` style, the `note` field is placed before the `url` field. However, you write-up seems to suggest that the "Accessed on" information must come after, not before, the `url` field. That's why I'm suggesting combining pieces of information related to the url and its accessed-on date in a single `note` field.

Comment: The use of the `agsm`style is not mandatory, but only the CiteThemRight standard. The only thing I am sure of is that the example I have given is needed, my supervisor has provided me with it. Would not using agsm make it possible to have the needed styling without modifying the .bib file?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the "CiteThemRight standard. (Is it explained somewhere on the Internet?) As I wrote earlier, your write-up seems to state that the `Date Accessed` information -- presumably contained in a field called `note`, right? -- must come after, not before, the `url` field. Unfortunately, that's not what the `agsm` style is set to do. If you can find a more suitable bib style, by all means switch to it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65942/fine-tuning-the-agsm-bibliography-style-and-adding-links) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436109/modify-the-agsm-bibliography-style-in-two-ways) answer of yours where you describe how to edit the `agsm` style directly. Could you please show me how I would do the same thing for my styling needs? I wager that it is possible because all needed values are in the bib file so I see no requirement to add it manually as a `note`.

Comment: @JFNT - You provided very little actionable information so far, except for the piece of information about the `agsm` bibliography style being in use. For all I know, you do not actually use the `note` field to record information about the last-access date. You've also provided no information about which entry type(s) you use. My earlier guess, that you employ the `@misc` entry type, may be utterly wrong. Without actionable information, it's well-nigh impossible to diagnose the situation accurately, let alone offer a cure.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It has taken me some time but I now have updated the question, if there is any more information I could provide please let me know.

Comment: @JFNT - Once there are more than a couple of hacks to make to an existing bib style file, it's generally a very good idea *not* to apply the hacks (and risk creating new bugs...) You've indicated a bunch of desired changes for entries of type `@article`. But what about the entries of type `@book`, `@misc`,etc? You should familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility, which is part of the `custom-bib` package. The `makebst` utility poses a sequence of multiple-choice questions, and its output is a bespoke bibliography style file that should meet most, if not all, of your requirements.

Comment: @JFNT - Do also note that there are already quite a few postings on this site related to topics such as changing the name of the bibliography section from, say, "Bibliography" to "References".